# Video does not match the width of the controls

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

[image]

```html
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-8 embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
    <video class="embed-responsive-item" width="100%" controls="controls">
           <source src="files/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>
```

I have tried different things but the video width won't fit the controls. I noticed that if I don't specify the width and set the Height to "auto" it does fit perfectly but the controls don't show anymore.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
    <title>page1</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
    <style>
        
        .center{
            position: fixed;
            right: 0em;
            top: 0em;
            min-width: 100%;
            min-height: 90%;
            image-resolution: 90%;
          
            
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <video class="center" width="100%" loop="true"   autoplay="autoplay" controls muted>
        <source src="files/video.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
    </video>
  
   
</body>
</html>
```

Try adding fullscreen styles! and never forget to  mute if you wanna autoplay!